# How can I replace words with their lemmas using spacyr?

Tags: r, quanteda

Having a dataframe like this:

```
library(spacyr)
df <- data.frame(id = c(102), text = c("the boy's cars are different colors"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

it is possible to make a part of speech tagging like this:

```
df2 <- spacy_parse(df$text, pos = TRUE, lemma = FALSE)
```

and use this to convert it to one row per document

```
df3 <- aggregate(lemma ~ doc_id, df2, paste, collapse = " ")
```

instead of doc_id how is it possible to keep the id?

The process provide a doc_id however I would like to merge the id of the input dataframe and parse data.

Example of expected output

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(102), text = c("the boy's car be different color"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: So you basically want to replace the words in your original text (in the first `df`) with the lemmatized words?

Comment: @KenBenoit thank you for your comment. Yes that's the option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way.  I'm using **dplyr** instead of `aggregate()`, and I've added to your example.

```r
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(102, 103),
  text = c(
    "the boy's cars are different colors",
    "The hare ran faster!"
  ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library("spacyr")
library("dplyr", warn.conflicts = FALSE)

spacy_parse(structure(df$text, names = df$id),
  lemma = TRUE, pos = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(id = doc_id) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(text = paste(lemma, collapse = " "))
## Found 'spacy_condaenv'. spacyr will use this environment
## successfully initialized (spaCy Version: 2.3.0, language model: en_core_web_sm)
## (python options: type = "condaenv", value = "spacy_condaenv")
## `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
## # A tibble: 2 x 2
##   id    text                             
##   <chr> <chr>                            
## 1 102   the boy 's car be different color
## 2 103   the hare run fast !
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Any idea please for this error `Error: invalid assignment for reference class field ‘docnames’, should be from class “character” or a subclass (was class “factor”)` ?

Comment: yes, make sure whatever you are assigning to docnames is a character, not a factor.